# PHP: Only show Headers/Subheads w/Answered Questions

Tags: php, forms, format

[image: PHP Form Results Page]

I would like it if someone could take a look at this page/screenshot and tell me how I can configure it to only show Headers & Subheads when they have answered a question in that section.

All of the questions are set up and working to only show when they've answered it.... but by default, all the Headers & Subheads show up... that's what needs fixing.

I could fix it if it were only 1 question per section, but I'm at a loss here.

[EDIT/ADD: There is a "Comment" section at the end, and that heading (along w/user comments) will only show up if they add a comment... by default, the "Comments" heading is not shown on the results page... Just don't know how to tie several questions to 1 heading or subhead w/out it duplicating every time!]

My questionnaire has 3 sections. Each section has roughly 30 questions. Those 30 questions are split up amongst different subsections.

Ex.If they answer No "History" questions, I don't want anything to show up for that entire section.
If they answer only 2 questions in "Exercise and Play", then I only want "History" and "Exercise and Play" to show up w/their two questions. And so forth.

How do you approach something like this???

Thank you in advance,
Tracy

```
<!-- HISTORY -->
<!-- ENVIRONMENT -->
<p class="data_hdr" style="margin-top:35px!important;">History</p>
<p class="data_subhd" style="margin-top:15px!important;">Environment</p>
<p class="data_answers">
<?php if (isset($_POST['typeofhouse'])) {echo '<strong>Type of House:        
</strong> '; if ($name == $typeofhouse) echo ($_POST['typeofhouse']); if 
($name == $othertypeofhouse) echo (' '); echo 
htmlspecialchars($_POST['othertypeofhouse']);} ?></p>
<p class="data_answers">
<?php if (isset($_POST['sleeping-arrangement'])) {echo '<strong>Sleeping 
Arrangement:</strong> '; echo htmlspecialchars($_POST['sleeping-
arrangement']);} ?></p>
<p class="data_answers">
<?php if (isset($_POST['pet-source'])) {echo '<strong>Pet Source:</strong> 
'; echo htmlspecialchars($_POST['pet-source']);} ?></p>
<p class="data_answers">
<?php if (isset($_POST['age-acquired'])) {echo '<strong>Age Acquired:
</strong> '; echo htmlspecialchars($_POST['age-acquired']);} ?></p>
<p class="data_answers">
<?php if (isset($_POST['number-of-people'])) {echo '<strong>Number of 
People:</strong> '; echo htmlspecialchars($_POST['number-of-people']);} ?>
</p>
<p class="data_answers">
<?php if (isset($_POST['neutered'])) {echo '<strong>Neutered:</strong> '; 
echo htmlspecialchars($_POST['neutered']);} ?></p>
<!-- IF NEUTERED=YES -->
<p class="data_answers">
<?php if (isset($_POST['whywasyourpetneutered'])) {echo '<strong>Why was 
your Pet Neutered:</strong> '; if ($name == $whywasyourpetneutered) echo 
($_POST['whywasyourpetneutered']); if ($name == $otherwhywasyourpetneutered) 
echo (' '); echo htmlspecialchars($_POST['otherwhywasyourpetneutered']);} ?>
</p>
<!-- WHY WAS YOUR PET NEUTERED=OTHER -->
<!-- IF NEUTERED-NO -->
<p class="data_answers">
<?php if (isset($_POST['are-you-interested-in-neutering'])) {echo 
'<strong>Are you Interested in Neutering:</strong> '; echo 
htmlspecialchars($_POST['are-you-interested-in-neutering']);} ?></p>
<p class="data_answers">
<?php if (isset($_POST['food-form'])) {echo '<strong>Food Form:</strong> '; 
echo htmlspecialchars($_POST['food-form']);} ?></p>
<p class="data_answers">
<?php if (isset($_POST['foodbrand'])) {echo '<strong>Food Brand:</strong> '; 
if ($name == $foodbrand) echo ($_POST['foodbrand']); if ($name == 
$otherfoodbrand) echo (' '); echo 
htmlspecialchars($_POST['otherfoodbrand']);} ?></p>
<!-- FOOD BRAND=OTHER -->
<p class="data_answers">
<?php if (isset($_POST['who-feeds'])) {echo '<strong>Who Feeds:</strong> '; 
echo htmlspecialchars($_POST['who-feeds']);} ?></p>
<p class="data_answers">
<?php if (isset($_POST['when-fed'])) {echo '<strong>When Fed:</strong> '; 
echo htmlspecialchars($_POST['when-fed']);} ?></p>
<p class="data_answers">
<?php if (isset($_POST['treats'])) {echo '<strong>Treats:</strong> '; echo 
htmlspecialchars($_POST['treats']);} ?></p>
<p class="data_answers">
<?php if (isset($_POST['table-food'])) {echo '<strong>Table Food:</strong> 
'; echo htmlspecialchars($_POST['table-food']);} ?></p>
<p class="data_answers">
<?php if (isset($_POST['tablefoodreaction'])) {echo '<strong>Table Food 
Reaction:</strong> '; if ($name == $tablefoodreaction) echo 
($_POST['tablefoodreaction']); if ($name == $othertablefoodreaction) echo (' 
'); echo htmlspecialchars($_POST['othertablefoodreaction']);} ?></p>


<!-- EXERCISE AND PLAY -->  
<p class="data_subhd">Exercise and Play</p>
<p class="data_answers">
<?php if (isset($_POST['hours-outside'])) {echo '<strong>Hours Outside:
</strong> '; echo htmlspecialchars($_POST['hours-outside']);} ?></p>
<p class="data_answers">
<?php if (isset($_POST['restraint'])) {echo '<strong>Restraint:</strong> '; 
echo htmlspecialchars($_POST['restraint']);} ?></p>
<p class="data_answers">
<?php if (isset($_POST['walks'])) {echo '<strong>Walks:</strong> '; echo 
htmlspecialchars($_POST['walks']);} ?></p>
<p class="data_answers">
<?php if (isset($_POST['leash-type'])) {echo '<strong>Leash Type:</strong> 
'; echo htmlspecialchars($_POST['leash-type']);} ?></p>
<p class="data_answers">
<?php if (isset($_POST['playtype'])) {echo '<strong>Play Type:</strong> '; 
if ($name == $playtype) echo ($_POST['playtype']); if ($name == 
$otherplaytype) echo (' '); echo htmlspecialchars($_POST['otherplaytype']);} 
?>
<!-- PLAY TYPE=OTHER -->
<p class="data_answers">
<?php if (isset($_POST['play-frequency'])) {echo '<strong>Play Frequency:
</strong> '; echo htmlspecialchars($_POST['play-frequency']);} ?></p>
```

Not sure if it makes a difference or not... but this is the page link to the form: http://www.safarivet.com/behavior-conditions/

Comment: We can't do much without code, *can you?* ;-)

Comment: You are expected to **try to write the code yourself**. After [**doing more research**](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/1011527) if you have a problem **post what you've tried** with a **clear explanation of what isn't working** and provide [a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Read [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) a good question. Be sure to [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/347937/1011527).

Comment: I have a blank slate in regards to this question, but I'll be happy to show the php I have setup right now. :)

Comment: Okay Jay. Well then someone feel free to delete this entire post.

Comment: You can delete the entire post yourself@flipflopmedia Outside of that your question is way too broad.

Comment: @Fred. PHP added above. Like I said, I could easily output the associated heading or subhead with the way the code is now, if I only had one question, but w/several per category, I'm not even sure how to approach it. Would it be setup as an array?

Comment: Man, that is some _messy_ code!

Comment: @Grumpy... GOOD NAME!!!

Comment: @flipflopmedia Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Got it working Beautifully, in the event someone comes across this post and needs the answer.

So now, regardless if the user answers 1 sub-category question or every sub-category question, the associated subhead will display; otherwise, it will not. Same for the main category heading; it will display if any answer in any sub-category is answered; otherwise, it will remain hidden by default.

My Approach (and of course, there are a million ways to do this, as with anything in this field; and of course, I am certain the code could be shorter, cleaner, ect... but it works!):

```
<!-- HISTORY -->
<!-- ENVIRONMENT "HEADINGS" -->
<?php
if(isset($_POST['typeofhouse']))
{ 
echo '<p class="data_hdr" style="margin-top:35px!important;">History</p>
<p class="data_subhd" style="margin-top:15px!important;">Environment</p>';
}

else if(isset($_POST['sleeping-arrangement']))
{ 
echo '<p class="data_hdr" style="margin-top:35px!important;">History</p>
<p class="data_subhd" style="margin-top:15px!important;">Environment</p>';
}
else if.... THE REST FOR "ENVIRONMENT" SUB-CATEGORY

/* EXERCISE & PLAY "HISTORY" HEADING */
else if(isset($_POST['hours-outside']))
{ 
echo '<p class="data_hdr" style="margin-top:35px!important;">History</p>';
}

else if(isset($_POST['restraint']))
{ 
echo '<p class="data_hdr" style="margin-top:35px!important;">History</p>';
}
?>

/* SUB-HEAD FOR "EXERCISE & PLAY */
<!-- EXERCISE AND PLAY "HEADING" -->
<?php
if(isset($_POST['hours-outside']))
{ 
echo '<p class="data_subhd" style="margin-top:15px!important;">Exercise and 
Play</p>';
}
else if(isset($_POST['restraint']))
{ 
echo '<p class="data_subhd" style="margin-top:15px!important;">Exercise and 
Play</p>';
}
else if.... THE REST FOR "EXERCISE & PLAY" SUB-CATEGORY
?>
```

The PHP Answer Sections remained the same as my previously pasted PHP, Except for deleting the Headers & Subheads (data_hdr & data_subhd) "P" Tags. The HTML Link (above) to the form still works for now. Once complete, it will be linked somewhere from the websites main menu.

Tracy